# setting margins of imageViews in gallery

Tags: android

I'm using gallery in android for showing images. My question is how can i set the margins of the  imageViews inside the gallery, so that they are not right next to each other but rather have some space between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/glr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my how i set the imageView in the gallery:

```
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageBitmap(photos[index]);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
    i.setLayoutParams(params);

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finnally it isn't possible to do so in a gallery got to make your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically when setting the images like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I've already tried this out this is the exception i get
LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams

Comment: don't put the parameters in the galery, put it in the imageviews.

Comment: I'm not, im putting it in the image imageview

Comment: try with ViewGroup.LayoutParams then since Gallery.LayoutParams descends from ViewGroup.LayoutParams